# Angular Ui-Grid Conditional CellTemplate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I need to show a button in my ui-grid as long as the field value is NOT an empty string.  I tried using `ng-if` but it is not working.  Here is the code in my grid options:

```
  { field: 'ReleaseStatus', 
    width: 125, 
    displayName: 'Release Status', 
    cellTemplate: 
    '<div ng-if="row.entity.ReleaseStatus != """>
        <button id="editBtn" 
            type="button" 
            class="btn btn-default"  
            data-toggle="modal" 
            data-target="#myModal" 
            ng-click="grid.appScope.launch(row)">
            {{COL_FIELD}}
        </button>
    </div>'
   },
```

Without the `ng-if` the button displays and works great.  However, because some records have an empty string for the field ReleaseStatus, the button should not appear.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should write it this way:

```
'<div ng-if="row.entity.ReleaseStatus !== \'\'">'
```

you can also put the ng-if directly on the buttom you are trying to hide.

however be careful of using ng-if because it creates a new scope everytime.

Comment: there is no "example" under "you should write this way".

Comment: I had to use the escape character '\' in order to use the single quotes.  I think it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**
There is a simple way to do this, please have a look on this example.

```
{
    name: 'nameishere', displayName: 'Display Name', cellTemplate:
       '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents" ng-if="grid.appScope.haveFile(row.entity.nameishere)"><a href="' + apiURL + '/InvalidFiles/{{row.entity.nameishere}}" download="{{row.entity.nameishere}}" >{{ row.entity.nameishere}}</a></div>'+
       '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents" ng-if="grid.appScope.haveNotFile(row.entity.nameishere)">{{ row.entity.nameishere}}</div>'
},
```

and create multiple functions OR use a function with if-else

```
$scope.haveFile    = function (data) { return data == 'No File to Display' };
$scope.haveNotFile = function (data) { return data != 'No File to Display' };
```

**Solution 2:** You should write it this way, string and integer handle in a different way.

```
cellTemplate:'<div ng-if="row.entity.status !== \'Your String Here\'">'
cellTemplate:'<div ng-if="row.entity.status  !== 23>'
```

**Solution 3:** Use ng-if like this

```
cellTemplate:'<div>{{row.entity.status  == 0 ? "Active" : (row.entity.status  == 1 ? "Non Active" : "Deleted")}}</div>';
```